# Can a PID be negative on Windows?

Tags: windows, process, pid

I am writing a method that takes PID as parameter. Can it be a negative number on Windows? If it can't be I will add a negative check to my method. But I couldn't find information on the internet.

Comment: PID is an identifier and nothing else. I wouldn't imagine having a negative PID at all neither in Unix or Windows. You could reject all negative PIDs by default and let the user tune that for themselves. Simply, no it can't be.

Comment: in all windows implementations *PID* is handle in special global handle table (can image that index). it never negative and always have form `4*n` where *n* some natural > 0. however for what you need check this at all ?

Comment: @RbMm taking a dependency on an implementation detail only leads to problems when the implementation changes.

Comment: @Richard - i simply explain what currently *pid* is. however i at all dont understand for what need any checks.

Comment: It is not a very sensible question, you must use the same data type that the OS uses.  Which is DWORD, an alias for `unsigned int`.  It isn't signed.  If you want to validate the argument then do it the correct way, use OpenProcess.  Or whatever you meant to do with that value.

Answer (score 5):

We only know they cannot be 0 or -1 (see *[Invalid thread and process IDs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040223-00/?p=40503)*).

So don't depend on them being positive (or, [multiples of four](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080228-00/?p=23283)).

Comment: If in some future implementation when negative is allowable, we then might all be lucky enough to be served with the reason why.